# How to delete a project shared with me?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Somebody shared with me a project and now when I try to delete it OR HIDE it I cant do that.

Does anybody knows how to hide that project from my list of projects?  I'm not interested to see it anymore.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what role you are given in the project. If you've 'owner' role then only you can delete the project or remove yourself from it.

If you've 'viewer' or 'editor' role then you can neither delete the project nor remove yourself from it, in that case, you've to reach out to folks who have 'owner' role in it and ask them to remove yourself from it or delete it.